# file:write_file/2 returns {error, badarg} when given a binary

Tags: erlang

I'm stuck with the very first programming exercise of Programming Erlang (2nd ed.) by Joe Armstrong. The second chapter introduces a brief program that runs locally both a file server and its client. The example only allows the client to list and get files from the server. The exercise requires you to enhance it by adding a `put_file` feature.

So I added a case condition to receive messages with the `put_file` atom and write them with the same filename as the source. Then I added a function to the client to read the contents of a file and send its name and contents to the server.

Unfortunately, each time the message reaches the server, the server tells me that I'm passing a bad argument to the `file:write_file/2` function (it returns `{error, badarg}`).
Assuming that the filename parameter is correct, I've checked the documentation and `file:read_file/1` returns a binary, while `file:write_file/2` takes an iodata, which, if I interpreted the docs correctly, can either be an iolist or binary.

```
iodata = iolist() | binary()
```

I'd say the types are right but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.

Here's the code.

afile_server.erl

```
-module(afile_server).
-export([start/1, loop/1]).

start(Dir) -> spawn(afile_server, loop, [Dir]).

loop(Dir) ->
  receive
    {Client, list_dir} ->
      Client ! {self(), file:list_dir(Dir)};
    {Client, {get_file, File}} ->
      Full = full(Dir, File),
      Client ! {self(), file:read_file(Full)};
    {Client, {put_file, File, Binary}} ->
      Full = full(Dir, File),
      Client ! {self(), file:write_file(Full, Binary)}
  end,
  loop(Dir).

full(Dir, File) -> filename:join(Dir, File).
```

afile_client.erl

```
-module(afile_client).
-export([ls/1, get_file/2, put_file/2]).

ls(Server) ->
  Server ! {self(), list_dir},
  receive
    {Server, FileList} ->
      FileList
  end.

get_file(Server, File) ->
  Server ! {self(), {get_file, File}},
  receive
    {Server, Content} ->
      Content
  end.

put_file(Server, File) ->
  Binary = file:read_file(File),
  Server ! {self(), {put_file, File, Binary}},
  receive
    {Server, ok} ->
      ls(Server);
    {Server, {error, Reason}} ->
      Reason
  end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file:read_file/1` returns `{ok, Binary}` or `{error, Reason}`. You are passing this as `Binary` in the `put_file` message, which is why you get an error when you try to give it to `file:write_file/2`.

Change

`Binary = file:read_file(File)`

to

`{ok, Binary} = file:read_file(File)`

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The implementations the client was bad, because Binary is like to String in Erlang, the function write_file don't need a file descriptor , It needs a Message, then if we rewrite the client function like to :

```
put_file(Server, File, Message) ->
  Server ! {self(), {put_file, File, Message}},
  receive
    {Server, ok} ->
      ls(Server);
    {Server, {error, Reason}} ->
      Reason
  end.
```

It's sufficient, and the call be  :

```
afile_client:put_file(Client,"lola","This message is in file."
```

I did this exercise in client:

```
{Client,{put_file,File,Message}} ->
          Full=filename:join(Dir,File),
          Client ! {self(),file:write_file(Full,Message)}
```

In server:

```
put_file(Server,File,Message) ->
        Server ! {self(),{put_file,File,Message}},
        receive
                {Server,Content}  ->
                        Content
        end.
```

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, Erik. :)